# Create column based on complex condition in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm "translating" a series of operations that were in Tableau into a pyspark script. One column in specific I'm having serious trouble to replicate, here the Tableu version of the code:

```
min(
     min(
          IF[COLUMN_A] > 0 THEN [COLUMN_B] ELSE 9999 END,
          IF[COLUMN_C] > 0 THEN [COLUMN_D] ELSE 99999 END),
     min(
          IF[COLUMN_E] > 0 THEN [COLUMN_F] ELSE 99999 END,
          IF[COLUMN_G] != 0 THEN [COLUMN_H] ELSE 99999 END)
)
```

Is it possible to create a version of that code using a `when` and `otherwise` functions in pyspark? I'm trying but it seems I can't solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark definitely supports chaining complex conditions. I suspect your point of failure is in the syntax, or not using `fun.lit` to wrap the `9999` scalar.

Anyway, assuming your columns are called 'A', 'B', ... 'H', the following should work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fun
...
fun.least(
    fun.least(
        fun.when(fun.col('A') > 0, fun.col('B')).otherwise(fun.lit(9999)),
        fun.when(fun.col('C') > 0, fun.col('D')).otherwise(fun.lit(9999))
            ),
    fun.least(
        fun.when(fun.col('E') > 0, fun.col('F')).otherwise(fun.lit(9999)),
        fun.when(fun.col('G') != 0, fun.col('H')).otherwise(fun.lit(9999))
            )
        )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I apply this code I'm  getting a "TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable"

Comment: Woops. `fun.min` operates within a single column. You need to use `fun.least` to operate across columns. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Just realized your 'not callable' error was being caused by a spelling mistake in `otherwise`. That is fixed too.